# Opening the first file(not empty) shows blank

Tags: neovim

After starting nvim, the first opened file always shows blank, the second will be back to normal. This issue is out of nowhere.
OS:Arch
nvim: 0.7.2
terminal: kitty

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm afraid your question seems more a bug report than a real question.  In order to help you we would need more information: about the symptom (a small screenshot would be helpful), the OS you are using, the version of Neovim that you are using, if you use the console version (nvim) of the GUI version (nvim-qt). Did you try to start nvim without considering the initialization `nvim -u NONE -i NONE`?

Comment: @Vivian De Smedt Thanks for your advice. Everything is ok when starts with initialization. How should I continue to locate the issue?

Comment: @Luxsis There are some tips here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file. For Neovim substitute in `init.vim`/`init.lua` whereever it reads `vimrc`

Comment: @Luxsis, my advice is very generic :-| remove half of the configuration and verify is you still have the problem if not remove the other half and repeat the action with the faulty half such that you can find the part that is causing the problem :-|. If you share our startup files we could try to reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: @Rich thanks for your advice

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thanks for your help, it's solved now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this issue is caused by wrong argument in nvim.packer.
Before I set `event="BufReadCmd"`for lazy loading, then I changed to `event="BufAdd"`.

I guess it's possible that loading package interrupts reading into buffer. Everything is back to noraml now.

Comment: Read `:help BufReadCmd`—it's supposed to the do the reading of the file. That would explain why you got a blank file.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks, I get it now